# Using composables with OptionsAPI

Tags: vuejs3, composable

Our team is converting an app from Vue 2 to 3 and I am working on the final steps.
I am investigating whether we can convert our mixin files to composables.  I have yet to find any documentation to support whether you can use composables with optionsAPI.
I have tried a little sample but I am seeing the limitations:

COMPOSABLE file useComposables:

```
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'

export default () => {
    let first = ref('First')
    let last = ref('Last')
    let mycomputed = computed(() => {
        return `${first.value} *** ${last.value}`
    })

    return {
        first, mycomputed
    }
}
```

COMPONENT:

```
import useComposables from '@/utils/useComposable'

created () {
        let { first, mycomputed } = useComposables()
        console.log('first', first.value)
        console.log('mycomputed', mycomputed.value)
    },

<template>
    mycomputed {{ mycomputed }}
</template>
```

So, I see when I try to do interpolation on `mycomputed` computed variable in the template, the component doesn't have access to the computed variable because it is not in the computed option and doesn't belong to 'this'.

I can't seem to find any documentation to support using composables with options API.
Am I missing something or is this a no-go?

Thanks

Comment: YOu can use the [setup function](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#basic-usage) instead of the created, and return your computed in there to access it from the template. I recommend you switch to composition API for [many benefits](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html#why-composition-api)

Comment: @Duannx title explicitly says "Using composables with OptionsAPI".

Comment: @kissu I just provide a better option

Comment: @Duannx obvious one that OP is probably aware of but the question is aimed towards this specific limitation (probably for good reasons). Otherwise, the solution is simple and straightforward and that question has no reason to exist.

Comment: @kissu Yeah, probably. That is why I leave a comment instead of an answer. If the OP is already aware of it, he can just move on. Take it easy.

Comment: @Duannx the current question is still quite interesting and deserves some attention. I'm curious myself tbh. Just giving an irrelevant answer will not help OP. It's like asking: "what is your age?" and getting "I really love strawberries, they are better than an age" as an answer.

Comment: @kissu I don't consider it irrelevant. Actually, I usually give kind of that answer. Because in my view, choosing the right approach is always the first thing we should do when resolving a problem. Some people are just interested in a straight answer but I am not that kind of person. So I will try to help others in my way. And the last thing, putting a comment in a question will never affect it in terms of seeking attention

Comment: Hey break it up guys!.  I did get it working by doing this:
```
setup() {
  let { first, mycomputed } = useComposables()

  return {
   first, mycomputed
  }
 },
```
Thanks

Comment: And my comment actually helps right? @DavidPell

Answer (score -2):

OP achieved to solve that by using the following:

```js
setup() {
    let { first, mycomputed } = useComposables()

    return {
        first, mycomputed
    }
},
```

Comment: Wow, you take other's people comments to your answer, again :)

Comment: @Duannx again, if you want to post an answer feel free. I can delete mine anytime. Wrote mine since nobody else did.

Comment: Because you don't wait long enough for others to take action. In this situation, I usually encourage the OP or the author of useful comments to post their answer. So they can get some reputation in the future. Some users just consider SO as a Q&A site but when they got some reputation, they really feel happy and tend to contribute more to the community. I think it is a better way to build our community

Comment: @Duannx sure. I don't wait because 90% of the time people just forget to post an actual answer and it gets into oblivion. Theory is nice, I'm applying practice and experience regarding my own daily journey. As I said, I can delete my answer any day if something more relevant pops up. Here, I just wanted to provide a quick and simple answer for anybody quickly scanning for an answer without reading all the comments (thing most people probably do not do). OP is not always aware that an answer could/should be posted, so I'm not waiting months for it to happen. Again, experience YMMW.

Comment: Your goal is good but the way you do it is making it a little weird. No one can wait for months but just some hours is too early. You can easily come back in a couple of days like the way you wait for another relevant answer to delete yours. Because if someone knows how SO works looking at your actions will have the same thinking as me that you are taking the chances of other people to get the reputation, tbh. Anyway, after a long conversation, I understood that you aim for a good purpose and I appreciate it

Comment: @Duannx I used to kinda ask people 12/24 hours later on. But, this is not really allowed by the platform (can put pressure on people) + it's quite consuming of my time since I do comment/answers on tons of questions per day. I do not keep track of all of them daily, too much mental work too. I meanwhile "follow" 90% of the questions I help on. Hence, if OP posts an answer in 18 months, I will gladly reply/delete my answer or whatever. By default, I'm assuming that OP will not answer here because this is my experience so far on the Nuxt/Vue tag.I will gladly give back credit to the one worth it